# SQOOP 1 failed to load Sybase driver - Could not load db driver class: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I am trying to import data from the sybaseIQ using sqoop-1. The `jdts-1.3.1.jar`     is placed on `/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib` folder.

When this syntax runs,

```
sqoop import  --connect '`jdbc:jtds:sybase:tds`://10.***.*.***@5500:*****' --driver 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'  --username "username" --password -p --query "select * from dw.DM_ADDRESS where rownum <= 1000 and \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir "/user/*****/WT_Address_Itc" --split-by 1 --verbose
and am getting this error:

17/03/02 11:15:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : select  * from dw.DM_ADDRESS_ITC where rownum <= 1000 and (1 = 0)
17/03/02 11:15:19 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:856)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForQuery(SqlManager.java:234)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:304)
at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:606)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

What am I missing here? Am I using the right driver? That's the one available on the http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ site?

I would really appreciate your help in this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver class `com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver` belongs to `jconn3.jar` 
Download `jconn3.jar` and place it in `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` directory.

And the connectionString must be,

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:dbhost:dbport/DATABASE=dbname
```

Comment: i have placed the jconn3.jar at the $SQOOP_HOME/lib and i have changed the connection string too...but running the script giving me this exception,

ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: JZ003: Incorrect URL format. URL:
    java.sql.SQLException: JZ003: Incorrect URL format. URL:
            at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
            at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.login(Unknown Source)

Comment: @karthee can you comment the exact connectstring used?

Comment: --connect 'jdbc:sybase:Tds://10.100.*.***:5500/DATABASE=iqprod1' --driver 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'

Comment: The `//` leading the host are not required. Try `jdbc:sybase:Tds:10.100.*.***:5500/DATABASE=iqprod1`

Comment: Thank you @franklinsijo. it runs quite fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea about SybaseIQ: the script is fine but am getting java.sql.SQLWarning: SQL Anywhere Error -103: Invalid user ID or password !!

Comment: Might be incorrect username/password provided to the sqoop command! Validate the username and password by trying to connect with Sybase directly.

Comment: let me check with my admin! Thanks again!

Comment: In your sqoop command, I see that `--password -p`. Is `-p` replaced with actual password when you are executing it?

Comment: yep...i have replaced with actual password.let me check with my admin, i might have using the expired pwd.

Comment: The connection is fine now. am getting the list-tables from DB.but when am running the simple query like select top 100 * from dm.address_itc,am getting this exception :ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '=' on line 1
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '=' on line 1

Comment: sqoop import  --connect 'jdbc:sybase:Tds:10.100.*.***:5500/DATABASE=iqprod1' --driver 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'  --username "keswara" --password -p --query "select top 100 * from dw.DM_ADDRESS_ITC" --target-dir "/user/keswara/WT_Address_Itc" --split-by 1 --verbose !!!! can you help me in this??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a new question with complete stacktrace!